# Is code snippet icon clear enough for new comers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, code-formatting, new-users

I see a lot of code snippets in new users questions which are not a code snippet actually, but just a code block. It seems some people click on snippet icon by mistake. Maybe the icon is misleading?

Comment: Both the icon and the term "code snippet" are misleading. "Code snippet" and "code block" are practically synonymous - it's the word *runnable* that distinguishes the two. The real problem here is that the UI doesn't make it clear that the feature is only intended for 1) *runnable* snippets 2) of HTML, CSS and JavaScript code only, until the user actually *clicks* the icon, at which time they become utterly confused as to why there are four panels and either try to wrangle this confusing UI (not knowing they're supposed to ignore it entirely if they're not a web developer) or give up.

Comment: The only way for a user new to this feature to know what it does right off the bat is 1) if they are a web developer who has used a similar external service before, or 2) if they had seen [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets). Talk about an utterly tragic case of [Guide Dang It](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GuideDangIt).

Comment: The button shouldn't be shown unless the tags [html] [css] or [jquery] are added to the question. *runs and hides from javascript dweebs*